# Why Account for Phylogeny when using Relative Brain Size as a Surragate for Intelligence

Tags: phylogenetics, biostatistics, intelligence, measurement

[This](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fevo.2020.00058/full) paper tries to relate intelligence, life history, and urban fitness of birds. They use relative brain size of each species as a surrogate measure of intelligence. Although this may not be the most accurate method, I understand why they used it. What I do not understand is why they used the method to calculate relative brain size that they did.

Rather than using the absolute relative brain size, they used "residual from a log-log phylogenetic Generalized Least Square regression... of absolute brain size against body mass". This means that relative brain size of a species is regarded as how large its brain is compared to its body size, compared to other species in its taxon. So if a species has a large brain and is part of a taxon that in general has larger brains could get a lower score than a species that has a small brain and is part of a taxon that in general has smaller brains.

Why is this not a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems they were attempting to correct for other behaviors/ecological niches that were correlated with brain size, but were not related to "urban tolerance". Their work includes much data on niches, behaviors, breeding strategies, etc, not just "urban tolerance".  Presumably, related species would share similar brain-size effects from these confounders, so residual differences could be correlated more specifically with "urban tolerance".

The authors comment:

> Because brain size correlates with these traits, failure to properly
> account for such additional drivers may mask the effect of brain size
> on urban tolerance. For example, if a large brain affects tolerance to
> urbanization by facilitating broader niches (Ducatez et al., 2015; Sol
> et al., 2016), including a measure of niche generalism in the model
> can block the effect of the brain on urban tolerance.

They are trying to correlate a quite crude measure (brain size) with a specific behavior ("urban tolerance"), which as you suggest raises all sorts of methodological questions.

Comment: I understand why they included factors such as niche breath in their model, but that does not explain why they used this calculation of relative brain size during data collection. I see no reason they could not have used absolute relative brain size and these other factors in their models.

Comment: I would think it's because they wanted to account for even unknown factors, but am not sure. Why not write the authors and ask? Researchers usually welcome intelligent questions about their work.